# How to manually change the Google Analytics tracking code on your website

Tags: html, google-analytics, tracking

A few months ago the Google Analytics tracking code on a website suddenly changed. It was different before and since it has changed, Google is not collecting any data anymore. The solution for this is to change the code on every page of the website to the new one, but to do it manually this will take me hours. Is there an easier way?

I already tried to link the new code to the old one in Google Analytics, but that doesn't give any result.

So... What I'm wondering is:
Is there a possibility to add your own tracking code in Google Analytics?
Or would it be possible to change the GA tracking code on the website **once** instead of doing it for every page?

Comment: What's the website framework?  WordPress, Django, Drupal, MyBB, etc.  Or is it just html files on a server?  Frameworks usually have the GA code installed in one place and then replicated across pages.  If however, you just have a bunch of static html pages on a server, then you might indeed need to change them all individually.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Its a WordPress website. Do you know if there is one place to add this code for all the pages? I didnt create the website myself so Im not sure how the GA code was implemented.

Comment: Usually WordPress sites either do this with a plugin, or with the theme.  I would first check the plugins page in the admin: /wp-admin/plugins.php.  You might see a Google Analytics plugin there, and you might be able to navigate to the place where you would change the code from that page.  Otherwise, it might be somewhere in the sidebar.  If, however, the GA code is installed using the theme, you might check the theme settings here: /wp-admin/customize.php.  It's basically just a matter of looking around for it in the admin.

Comment: Perfect, I found the right place to change it for the whole website @kloddant!! Thank you so much for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace it you will have to change the code that is currently present on the pages with the one you want. So if it was entered manually in all pages you will inevitably have to change it in each of them.

Based on how the site is structured, usually, there are inclusion files that call pieces of code in the pages, so if you have an inclusion file in the `head` and this is called up in all the pages, you can insert the tracking code there inside one time.

However, this is not a problem of Google Analytics, but of website creation basics.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @kloddant I found the answer by searching in the theme options > advanced > code fields (tracking) and there I could change the GA code for the entire website.